# How to access a superview's view controller from a child view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm creating a `UIView` that will have a `UITableView` inside it. I want to set this `UITableView` delegate and data source equal to the view controller of its superview.

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class AllTasksView: UIView {

    let tableview = UITableView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
     override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    tableview.delegate = "SUPERVIEW.ViewController"
    tableview.dataSource = "SUPERVIEW.ViewController"
}
```

Is it possible to do so like this? and where is it best to `override` the `UITableview` methods? I have already done so in my `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

Due to separation of concerns, you cannot access a `UIViewController` from a `UIView`.

Alternatively, you can use delegation to access the `UIViewController`

```
   class AllTasksView{
       weak var delegate: UITableViewDataSource & UITableviewDelegate?{
           didSet{
               tableView.delegate = newValue
               tableView.dataSource = newValue
           }
       }


   }
```

**ADDITIONAL**

```
       class CustomVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
          //implement tableview methods here 


           func viewDidLoad(){
               super.viewDidLoad()

              let allTasksView = AllTasksView()
              view(addSubview: allTasksView)

              //add some positioning and size constraints here for allTasksView 

              allTasksView.delegate = self //this would call the didSet and would automatically setup the allTasksView.tableView's delegate and dataSource to this vc
           }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joshua. Can you explain further how this process works and what should i add in the newValue.

Comment: the newValue is a special constant inside didSet. In this case, it would be the value of CustomVc

Comment: allTasksView.delegate = self , this doesn't work since allTasksView doesn't have a member called delegate. do you mean allTasksView.table.delegate = self?

Comment: No, I really meant `allTasksView.delegate = self`. Please refer to initial code snippet to add `delegate` property to AllTasksView instances